# RegEx - Password Strength

Tags: regex, passwords

I'm trying to make a regex for allowing only *strong* passwords, strong in this case being defined as:

- Must start with a letter (either uppercase or lowercase)
- Must have at least 8 and up to 12 characters
- Must have at least one uppercase letter
- Must have at least three lowercase letters
- Must have at least two numbers
- Must have at least two special characters
- **Maximum number of identical consecutive characters is three**

Now, last one is giving me trouble. How do I count consecutive characters?

For example, `FOOfoo!?123` should work, but `FOOOfoo!?12` should not (because or three esses).

What I've got so far:

```
^[A-Za-z]{1}(?=.*[A-Z]{1,})(?=.*[a-z]{3,})(?=.*[0-9]{2,})(?=.*[!?@*#&$]{2,}).{8,12}$
```

One more thing: something is amiss, because my regex above claims strings like `FooFoo!?123` are invalid. I *think* it's because it only checks for one or more uppercase letters **or** three or more lowercase letters **or** numbers **or** specials, but I don't want that, I want that is the password contains three lowercase letters *in total*, it should be valid. How do I do that?

Comment: Please tell me you don't actually enforce the above horrible rules on users and it's just a strength guideline.

Comment: The last but one 3 conditions are implemented in the regex as if they were *Must have at least three/two ... chars **at a stretch***. Is that what you intended to match?

Comment: `Must have at least two numbers`. If I am understanding your expression correctly, the expression will match *only if* the numbers are consecutive.

Comment: `up to 12 characters` why would you limit the maximum length?

Comment: Try [`^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})(?=(?:[^!?@*#&$]*[!?@*#&$]){2})(?!.*(.)\1{2})[A-Za-z].{7,11}$`](https://regex101.com/r/xC2lT6/1)

Comment: Actually this is not a that strong password and the only good password are passphrase :)

Comment: Complex password rules will usually not lead to more safe passwords, really important is only a minimum length, see also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34307812/575765).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have so many conditions, it might be a good idea - provided your environment allows that - to split the regex and check each condition separately.

If you cannot do that, here is a free-spacing version of the fixed regex:

```
^                                 # start of string
 (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])                 # At least 1 uppercase ASCII letter
 (?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})          # at least 3 lowercase ASCII letters
 (?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){‌​2})          # at least 2 ASCII digits
 (?=(?:[^!?@*#&$]*‌​[!?@*#&$]){2})  # at least 2 special symbols
 (?!.*(‌​.)\1{2})                   # No 3 consecutive characters
 [A-Za-z]                         # An ASCII letter
 .{7,‌​11}                          # 7 to 11 any characters but newline
$                                 # end of string
```

As a one-liner:

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3})(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){2})(?=(?:[^!?@*#&$]*[!?@*#&$]){2})(?!.*(.)\1{2})[A-Za-z].{7,11}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xC2lT6/1)

Notes:

- *Must have at least three lowercase letters* and similar conditions are implemented using the principle of contrast, i.e. before `[a-z]`, we may have 0+ opposite chars matched with `[^a-z]`.
- To match the 3 letters *globally*, not *consecutively*, we need to use a limiting quantifier on the grouping, not on the character class, thus, `[a-z]{3,}` (=consecutive 3 or more lowercase letters) is turned into `(?:[^a-z]*[a-z]){3}` (=3 sequences of non-lowercase letters followed with 1 lowercase letter).
- The condition you needed is `(?!.*(‌​.)\1{2})` - a negative lookahead (`(?!...)`) that checks for the presence of any character captured with `(.)` that is repeated twice after it with the `\1` backreference and `{2}` limiting quantifier set on the backreference. And `.*` means that the repeated characters may appear anywhere in the string.